# How to interpret the coefficients of a regressor in a ARIMAX model

Tags: forecasting, arima, statsmodels

I'm fitting an ARIMAX model with statsmodels SARIMAX library. I've done a logarithm transformation for both the dependent variable and the regressor and I've been left with the following coefficients:

[image]

How should I interpret the coefficient of the regressor log_totalmovement?